# assert which layout is loaded?

Tags: android, testing

i am setting two different layouts,one for landscape mode and one for portrait mode.
now i want to assert which one is set 
public void testOrienationChange() {

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
            assert which one is visible/set
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
assert which one is visible/set
```

how to test which layout is set or visible from test class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            // Checks the orientation of the screen
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                Log.e("Orientation obsetvationActivity", "landscape");
                Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                Log.e("Orientation obsetvationActivity", "portrait");
                Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

And in Your manifest under Activity (`<Activity ...>`) tag add this

```
android:configChanges="screenSize"
```